# Php fatal error Uncaught PDOException

Tags: php, mariadb

I have problem like this

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'TekstSrpski='Nova vakcina protiv HIV virusa prošla je početna ispitivanja ' at line 1 in
>    C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\izmenivest.php:77 Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\izmenivest.php(77): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\unija\aids\admin\izmenivest.php on line 77

On Code
I can't post code here i don't know why so i upload it on http://www.gamers.rs/izmeni.txt
Plese somebodey help me :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at the [ask] and paste your code directly. Have you printed the query in php to see, what is beeing sent to the  database?

Comment: Put your code in the question, not anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

1064 error message always says "near..." and it almost always points exactly at or immediately after the bad syntax.

Check the punctuation (or lack of it) just before `TekstSrpski=...`